# local storage loses property when submit a form

Tags: javascript, storage, local

I'm working on a toDo project with local storage. When i try do update the local storage it works perfectly. But after pressing the submit button and the page is reloading the data gets lost. I'm trying to update the name and the description. To update the name works fine, but the description doesn't. I don't get the problem. Between update the property and reloading the page the code didn't do anything.

I'm starting to despair ;)

```
function _editProjectHeader() {
    addProjectContainer.style.visibility = 'visible';

    projectNameContainer.value = _getActiveProject().getName();
    projectDescriptionContainer.value = _getActiveProject().getDescription();

    addProjectBtnSmallWindow.addEventListener('click', () => {
        _getActiveProject().setName(projectNameContainer.value); // Works fine
        _getActiveProject().setDescription(projectDescriptionContainer.value); // works fine to before update the page
        console.log(projectList);
        console.log(localStorage); // Here the data is stored in localstorage 
    })
}
```

Now after reloading the page, first I do a console log localstorage and the property didn't stored in it. How is that possible?

Get the active project from project list. The list stores all projects with name and description

```
function _getActiveProject() {
    const amountOfProjects = Object.keys(projectList).length;
    for (let i = 0; i <= amountOfProjects; i++) {
        if (projectList.getSingleProjects(i).isActive() == true) {
            return projectList.getSingleProjects(i)
        }
    }
}
```

My project class

```
import { toDate, isToday, isThisWeek, subDays } from 'date-fns'
import { projectList } from '../index';

export class Projects {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tasks = {};
        this.active = false;
        this.description = '';
    }

    setName(name) {
        this.name = name;
        projectList.safeToProjectList(this);
    }

    setActiveTrue() {
        this.active = true;
        projectList.safeToProjectList(this);
    }

    isActive() {
        return this.active ? true : false;
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    setDescription(decription) {
        this.description = decription;
        projectList.safeToProjectList(this);
    }

    getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    addTaskToList(task) {
        this.tasks[task.name] = task;
    }

    getTasks() {
        return this.tasks;
    }

    getTasksToday() {
        return this.tasks.filter((task) => {
          const taskDate = new Date(task.getDateFormatted())
          return isToday(toDate(taskDate))
        })
    }
    
    getTasksThisWeek() {
        return this.tasks.filter((task) => {
          const taskDate = new Date(task.getDateFormatted())
          return isThisWeek(subDays(toDate(taskDate), 1))
        })
    }

    updateLocalStorage() {
        
    }

}
```

And my project list class where I store my projects

```
import { Projects } from "./project";
import { Tasks } from "./tasks";

export class ProjectList {
    constructor() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('list') != null) {
            this.projectList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));
            console.log('loading existing data');
        } else {
            this.projectList = {};
            localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(projectList));
            console.log('setting new data');
        }
    }

    safeToProjectList(project) {
        this.projectList[project.getName()] = project;
        localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(this.projectList));
    }

    deleteProjectFromList(project) {
        delete this.projectList[project]
        localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(this.projectList))
    }

    loadProjectList() {
       this.projectList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'))
    }

    updateTodayTasks() {
        const today = new Projects('inbox');
        const amountOfProjects = Object.keys(this.projectList).length - 1;
        for (let i = 0; i <= amountOfProjects; i++) {
            const tasks = [Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].getTasksToday()
            if (tasks.length > 0) {
                today.addTaskToList(tasks);
            }
        }
        return today;
    }

    updateWeekTasks() {
        const thisWeek = new Projects('thisWeek');
        const amountOfProjects = Object.keys(this.projectList).length - 1;
        for (let i = 0; i <= amountOfProjects; i++) {
            const tasks = [Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].getTasksThisWeek()
            if (tasks.length > 0) {
                thisWeek.addTaskToList(tasks);
            }
        }
        return thisWeek;
    }

    updateInboxTasks() {
        const inbox = new Projects('thisWeek');
        const amountOfProjects = Object.keys(this.projectList).length - 1;
        for (let i = 0; i <= amountOfProjects; i++) {
            const tasks = [Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].getTasks();
            if (tasks.length > 0) {
                inbox.addTaskToList(tasks);
            }
        }
        return inbox;
    }

    getNameFromProjects() {
        const nameArray = [];
        const amountOfProjects = Object.keys(this.projectList).length - 1;
        for (let i = 0; i <= amountOfProjects; i++) {
            const name = [Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].getName();
            nameArray.push(name);
        }
        return nameArray
    }
    
    setProjectsActiveFalse() {
        const amountOfProjects = Object.keys(this.projectList).length - 1;
        for (let i = 0; i <= amountOfProjects; i++) {
            [Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].active = false;
        }
        //Local storage
        this.safeCurrentProject();
    }

    getSingleProjects(i) {
        //Build here new Project
        let project = new Projects([Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].name);

        //Set active bool
        if ([Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].active ==  true) {
            project.setActiveTrue();
        };

        //Add description
        project.setDescription([Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].description);

        //Add tasks
        const tasks = [Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0].tasks;
        const newTasks = Object.values(tasks).length - 1
        if (newTasks > 0) {
            // const amountOfProjects = Object.keys(this.projectList).length - 1;
            for (let x = 0; x <= newTasks; x++) {
                //Filter data from tasks
                //Add new task
                const taskName = [Object.values(tasks)[x]][0].name;
                const taskDate = [Object.values(tasks)[x]][0].dueDate;
                const taskPriority = [Object.values(tasks)[x]][0].priority;
                const taskProject = [Object.values(tasks)[x]][0].project;
                const taskComplete = [Object.values(tasks)[x]][0].complete;

                const task = new Tasks(taskName, taskDate, taskPriority, taskProject, taskComplete);
                project.addTaskToList(task);
            }
        }
        return project;
    }

    safeCurrentProject() {
        localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(this.projectList));
    }

}
```

The whole code
https://github.com/SandyWezzy/toDo_list

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's the concept of variables (`[Object.values(tasks)[x]][0]`, `[Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0]`) ;)

Comment: Wrapping an element in an array and then immediately unwrap that element is not the best way: `[Object.values(tasks)[x]][0]`, `[Object.values(this.projectList)[i]][0]`.

Comment: can you explain why or give me a kind of solution?  Especially 
why did this happen after pressing submit. I'm still trying to get the problem  @Andreas